# new version cloud 9 : how to deploy to heroku

Tags: heroku, cloud9-ide

How to deploy a web application to heroku in new version of cloud9 ?
The previous version had the deploy button, but cannot be found in new version

Comment: Why is this down voted? It is a valid question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the new version of Cloud9 we don't have support for deployment from the UI yet unfortunately, but we're going to add those features soon. In the meantime, we recommend using the command line from the built-in terminal, as described on our documentation site here: https://docs.c9.io/deploying_via_cli.html

Comment: I spent ages trying to find the "balloon deploy icon" as I was following this guide to deploy to openshift. Turns out from what you say, that we have to deploy using command line now. Why did cloud9 remove an existing feature? https://c9.io/blog/you-can-now-deploy-to-openshift/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the directions that Ivar published above you may need some additional steps.

For Rails deployment you need to:

1) Add your SSH key via the command line to heroku using: $ heroku keys:add

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

2) Remove SQLite and add Postgresql

Directions and source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this too but I have already setup my deployment using snap-ci.com it takes about a minute and when you check into your repository snap-ci will deploy it to heroku for you. I know it doesn't exactly answer your question but its a very simple alternative. I would add that down the road if you need additional deployment steps you are already part way there if you use a CI system.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it via c9 command line as there were some proxy issues which I couldn't figure out in my local computer.